# Applescript Check for Flash Player Update in System Preferences

Tags: user-interface, applescript

I've made it to here:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Flash Player"
            click radio button "Advanced" of tab group 1
            tell scroll area "Advanced"
                click button "Check Now" of window 2    
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

but I can't get applescript to click the "Check Now" Button. 
I'm thinking I need to add another `tell application "System Events"` to click the second area of the advanced tab, but so far I just get errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works perfectly at me:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "System Preferences"
        tell window "Flash Player"
            tell tab group 1
                click radio button "Advanced"
                tell scroll area 1
                    click button "Check Now"
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

In such cases the tool [Accessibility Inspector](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Accessibility/Conceptual/AccessibilityMacOSX/OSXAXTesting/OSXAXTestingApps.html) is very helpful.